# How to get client rects in a visual viewport in current google chrome?

Tags: javascript

I created a script which allocates an overlay to a clicked element:

```
(() => {
  const d = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  Object.assign(d.style, {
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "black",
    opacity: "0.3",
    transition: "500ms",
  });
  window.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
    const rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    Object.assign(d.style, {
      top: `${rect.top + scrollY}px`,
      left: `${rect.left + scrollX}px`,
      width: `${rect.width}px`,
      height: `${rect.height}px`,
    });
  });
})();
```

This overlay does not work right if Google Chrome are pinched zoom.

Because `scrollX`/`scrollY` are **visual viewport** offsets and `getBoundingClientRect`/`getClientRects` are relative coordinates from a top-left of a **layout viewport**. I know that these viewport are different in Google Chrome pinched zoom.

I need one of next coordinates to the above script working right:

1. Client rects which are relative coordinates from the top-left from the visual viewport
2. Layout viewport offsets
3. Relative coordinates of visual viewport from top-left of the layout viewport

Answer (score 0):

I realized it with "Layout viewport offsets" using the rect of the root element:

```
function getLayoutViewportOffsets() {
  const rootRect = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { y: - rootRect.top, x: - rootRect.left };
}
function getVisualViewportOffsets() {
  return { y: window.scrollY, x: window.scrollX };
}
function getBoundingClientRectFromRoot(element) {
  const layoutVpOffsets = getLayoutViewportOffsets();
  const layoutVpRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    top: layoutVpRect.top + layoutVpOffsets.y,
    bottom: layoutVpRect.bottom + layoutVpOffsets.y,
    left: layoutVpRect.left + layoutVpOffsets.x,
    right: layoutVpRect.right + layoutVpOffsets.x,
    height: layoutVpRect.height,
    width: layoutVpRect.width,
  };
}
function getBoundingClientRectFromVisualViueport(element) {
  const absoluteRect = getBoundingClientRectFromRoot(element);
  const visualVpOffsets = getVisualViewportOffsets();
  return {
    top: absoluteRect.top - visualVpOffsets.y,
    bottom: absoluteRect.bottom - visualVpOffsets.y,
    left: absoluteRect.left - visualVpOffsets.x,
    right: absoluteRect.right - visualVpOffsets.x,
    height: absoluteRect.height,
    width: absoluteRect.width,
  };
}
```